# Why is ICopyHook handler useful on shared folders?

Tags: windows, com, windows-shell, windows-explorer

[During reading a MSDN document about ICopyHook interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I got a curious.

> Implement a copy hook handler when you want to be able to control when, or if, these file system operations are performed on a given object. **You might want to use a copy hook handler on shared folders, for example.**

But I can't imagine this case. Could you explain why did they refer to shared folders?
And very helpful if you give some more examples to use copyhook.

Comment: I'm guessing you should read "shared folders" as "folders accessible by multiple users".  So you can stop one user from copying or deleting the files of another user.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it a filesystems'(network redirector here) responsbility, though? If they did implement to return STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION properly, I think there is no problem by multiple users.

Comment: Well, the primary point of the hook is to prevent users from having to deal with sharing violations.  An app could use the hook to close a file and thus prevent the violation.  If this works cross-network then that's a feature I never heard of.  I highly doubt it.

Comment: @HansPassant When we delete a folder, Windows Explorer deletes each child files first, then delete the folder. If the folder has 100 files, we get 101 Irps. This is a serious problem in a network volume. Our network filesystem can delete the folder regardless of having child files, in a constant time. So I used the hook to change the Explorer's behavior, and it worked well. I thought this is main purpose why they made this hook.(Maybe I was wrong) My head doesn't understand your this sentence `An app could use the hook to close a file and thus prevent the violation` yet. ::cry::

Comment: Not sure I follow, you can't exactly change Explorer's behavior with the hook.  All you can do is prevent it from executing SHFileOperation by returning IDNO or IDCANCEL.  What does your hook actually do?

Comment: I'm making network redirector driver like SMB/CIFS. Installed the hook, and catch the operations. If the operation is not our volume, we just return ID_YES to process normally. If the operation is DELETE and on our volume, we call the `folder deletion command` to our network server then return ID_NO. Explorer doesn't do anything anymore, but the operation is done well.

Comment: @HansPassant There is another example. If we mount two volumes at X: and Z:. If we rename a folder X: to Z:, READ and WRITE irps come if there is no hook because it's the different volume. We catch this and call `folder rename command` to our network filesystem server. So it can be done much fast. Do you think these are abusing?

Comment: @HansPassant One bad thing is, if `the delete or rename command` fails, we should show our own messagebox to users.

Comment: Well, you can, that's what the HWND argument is for, it is the parent window you should use to display your own dialog.  I'm getting a bit lost, what is the actual question?

Comment: @HansPassant I was just curious why did they use the example `shared folder` because there is no comment anymore. It seems like to prevent sharing violation problem like you said. But I still don't understand why/how do we prevent the problem with using the hook.

Comment: Back to my original comment.  Shared by multiple users on one machine, not shared across a network.  Preventing a sharing violation is an obvious use case, but you can also prevent a file from getting messed with.  I think what you are looking for is a scenario where a user on machine A accesses a shared folder on machine B.  What network redirectors support.  Hoping that explorer.exe on A will call a copy hook registered on B is surely idle hope.

Comment: @HansPassant +1s For your precious time. `Shared by multiple users on one machine` Now I understood. I thought `shared folder` means `network shared folder`.